# Text substitution like C macros

Tags: rust

I have a function used to log errors

```
trait LogTrait {
    fn log(self, mess: &str, file: &str, line: u32) -> Self;
}

impl<T, E> LogTraitfor Result<T, E>
where
    E: std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn log(self, mess: &str, file: &str, line: u32) -> Self {
        if let Err(err) = &self {
            fs::write("errors.log", format!("{:1} :F{:2}L{:3}",
                mess, file, line.to_string().as_str())
            );
        }
        self
    }
}
```

Used this way

```
SomeFunction.log("my message", file!(), line!())?
```

In C++, I would create a macro to only fill in my `message`, but keeping calling `file!()` and `line!()` where the macro is called:

```
#define LOG(MESSAGE) log(MESSAGE, file!(), line!())
```

I know Rust's macros cannot be used for text substitution. But what is the proper way to achieve that in Rust, then?

Comment: A macro, without text substitution?

Comment: Or even not a macro maybe. But how to call ```file!()``` and ```line!()``` on the good line?

Comment: A macro will be replaced with the correct lines. Though I'd use a `#[track_caller]` function.

Comment: Are you after [`std::panic::Location::caller()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller)?  The returned `Location` has [`file`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/panic/struct.Location.html#method.file) and [`line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/panic/struct.Location.html#method.line) methods that return the file and line of the calling code (or, with @ChayimFriedman's suggestion of applying `#[track_caller]` to your `log` function, its caller's code).

Comment: @eggyal Location::caller() is indeed a perfect alternative! Thank you.